# Is there a way to auto-input sql script prompts?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sqlscript that contains statements like this:

```
prompt Enter 'html' for an HTML report, or 'text' for plain text
prompt  Defaults to 'html'

column report_type new_value report_type;
set heading off;
select 'Type Specified: ',lower(nvl('&&report_type','html')) report_type from dual;
```

So when I run the script it prompts me to enter in values. I want to automate this script. How would I pass to the script parameters that are then used for the prompts? I cannot modify the script at all by removing the prompts.

I am using Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix you can use here documents:

```
#>sqlplus un @script <<EOF
yourpassword
parameter#1
parameter#2
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're passing values in from the command line or a batch file etc you can pass in parameters by using `&1, &2, .. &n`, where the number is the position of the parameter when calling

```
column report_type new_value report_type
set heading off

select 'Type Specified: ',lower(nvl('&1','html')) report_type from dual;
```

This would be called by

```
[call sqlplus schema/pw@db @] my_script.sql html
```

Incidentally you don't need semi-colons after SQL*Plus commands.

Comment: The script has the prompts and I can't modify the script by removing the prompts.

Comment: A prompt, by definition, prompts. I'm not suggesting that you remove the variables just that you assign them in a different way.

Comment: What I'm saying is the prompt waits for you to enter a value. How do I get past the prompts without removing them from the script when I want to automate the script?

Comment: Don't use prompts... use the method I've suggested ( or set the variable dynamically but that's more complicated ). A prompt will _always_ ask for a value. You have to set the value before you get asked for it.

Comment: Well, someone else wrote the sql script and I'm not allowed to rewrite it, so I'm just going to have to figure something else out. Thanks!