# How to install postgres on ubuntu without terminal prompts

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get postgres to install on ubuntu xenial by automating the process entirely. I expected it would go smoothly like any other apt-get, but in the middle it asks me to configure where I'm from (region and city). However, I want it to get done without me actually having to type in more than the initial command.
What I'm using so far is:

```
apt-get install -y postgresql
```

basically, I need it to input two values when the installation asks: 8 for region and 61 for city.

Since my knowledge of terminal commands is weak, I'd appreciate either simple and/or thoroughly explained suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Set the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive`. E.g., here's how to do it scoping to just the postgresql installation command:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y postgresql
```

Comment: Also works on Docker: `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND ...`.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this exact problem and this was what helped me automate the install process. From Robert Merkwürdigeliebe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282819/10893937

```
#>sqlplus un @script <<EOF
yourpassword
parameter#1
parameter#2
EOF
```